# MongoDB - Generating dynamic $or using pipeline variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

hoping someone can help as I am truly stuck!

I have this query

```
SwapModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            organisationId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(organisationId),
            matchId: null,
            matchStatus: 0,
            offers: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    from: { $lte: new Date(from) },
                    to: { $gte: new Date(to) },
                    locations: { $elemMatch: { $eq: location } },
                    types: { $elemMatch: { $eq: type } },
                },
            },
//problem is HERE
            $or: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$offers",
                    as: "offer",
                    in: {
                        from: { $gte: new Date("$$offer.from") },
                        to: { $lte: new Date("$$offer.to") },
                        location: { $in: "$$offer.locations" },
                        type: { $in: "$$offer.types" },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    { ...swapUserLookup },
    { $unwind: "$matchedUser" },
    { $sort: { from: 1, to: 1 } },
]);
```

I'm trying to use the results of the `$match` document to generate an array for `$or`. My data looks like this:

```
[{
    _id: ObjectId("id1"),
    from: ISODate("2023-01-21T06:30:00.000Z"),
    to: ISODate("2023-01-21T18:30:00.000Z"),
    matchStatus: 0,
    matchId: null,
    userId: ObjectId("ddbb8f3c59cf13467cbd6a532"),
    organisationId: ObjectId("246afaf417be1cfdcf55792be"),
    location: "Chertsey",
    type: "DCA",
    offers: [{
        from: ISODate("2023-01-23T05:00:00.000Z"),
        to: ISODate("2023-01-24T07:00:00.000Z"),
        locations: ["Chertsey", "Walton"],
        types: ["DCA", "SRV"],
    }]
}, {
    _id: ObjectId("id2"),
    from: ISODate("2023-01-23T06:30:00.000Z"),
    to: ISODate("2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z"),
    matchStatus: 0,
    matchId: null,
    userId: ObjectId("d6f10351dd8cf3462e3867f56"),
    organisationId: ObjectId("246afaf417be1cfdcf55792be"),
    location: "Chertsey",
    type: "DCA",
    offers: [{
        from: ISODate("2023-01-21T05:00:00.000Z"),
        to: ISODate("2023-01-21T07:00:00.000Z"),
        locations: ["Chertsey", "Walton"],
        types: ["DCA", "SRV"],
    }]
}]
```

I want the $or to match all documents that have the corresponding from/to/location/type as the current document - the idea is two shifts that could be swapped

If the offers are known (passed as an array to the function calling `aggregate`), I can do this with:

```
$or: offers.map((x) => ({
            from: { $gte: new Date(x.from) },
            to: { $lte: new Date(x.to) },
            location: { $in: x.locations },
            type: { $in: x.types },
        }))
```

**BUT** I want to be able to do this in an aggregation pipeline when the `offers` will only be known from the current document, `$offers`

Is this possible? I've tried `$in, $map, $lookup, $filter, $getField` but can't get it right and can't get anything from Google as it thinks I want $in (which is the opposite of what I need).

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and am probably approaching this completely wrong but I'd really appreciate any help!

Edit: expected output is simply an array of matching documents, so passing document id1 to the function would return an array with id2 in, because each document is compatible with the other

```
///expected output, from and to are between an offer in id1's from and to, similarly types/locations are compatible
{
    _id: ObjectId("id2"),
    from: ISODate("2023-01-23T06:30:00.000Z"),
    to: ISODate("2023-01-23T18:30:00.000Z"),
    matchStatus: 0,
    matchId: null,
    userId: ObjectId("d6f10351dd8cf3462e3867f56"),
    organisationId: ObjectId("246afaf417be1cfdcf55792be"),
    location: "Chertsey",
    type: "DCA",
    offers: [{
        from: ISODate("2023-01-21T05:00:00.000Z"),
        to: ISODate("2023-01-21T07:00:00.000Z"),
        locations: ["Chertsey", "Walton"],
        types: ["DCA", "SRV"],
    }]
```

### Solution

Based on the accepted answer I was able to create a self-lookup, the missing componenet was the reciprocal match using `$anyElementTrue` to search the `offers` field

I suspect there is a more optimised approach

[Mongo playground working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3-mND8mrKUD)

```
db.swaps.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {},
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$offers",
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "swaps",
            as: "matches",
            let: {
                parentId: "$_id",
                parentOrganisationId: "$organisationId",
                parentUserId: "$userId",
                parentLocations: "$offers.locations",
                parentTypes: "$offers.types",
                parentOffersFrom: "$offers.from",
                parentFrom: "$from",
                parentTo: "$to",
                parentOffersTo: "$offers.to",
                parentLocation: "$location",
                parentType: "$type",
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        matchStatus: 0,
                        matchId: null,
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $ne: ["$_id", "$$parentId"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $ne: ["$userId", "$$parentUserId"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $eq: [
                                        "$organisationId",
                                        "$$parentOrganisationId",
                                    ],
                                },
                                {
                                    $in: ["$location", "$$parentLocations"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $in: ["$type", "$$parentTypes"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $lte: ["$$parentOffersFrom", "$from"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $gte: ["$$parentOffersTo", "$to"],
                                },
                                {
                                    $anyElementTrue: {
                                        $map: {
                                            input: "$offers",
                                            as: "offer",
                                            in: {
                                                $and: [
                                                    {
                                                        $in: [
                                                            "$$parentLocation",
                                                            "$$offer.locations",
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        $in: [
                                                            "$$parentType",
                                                            "$$offer.types",
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        $lte: [
                                                            "$$offer.from",
                                                            "$$parentFrom",
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        $gte: [
                                                            "$$offer.to",
                                                            "$$parentTo",
                                                        ],
                                                    },
                                                ],
                                            },
                                        },
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "users",
                        localField: "userId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "matchedUser",
                    },
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        matchedUser: {
                            $ifNull: [
                                {
                                    $first: "$matchedUser",
                                },
                                null,
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            doc: {
                $first: "$$ROOT",
            },
            matches: {
                $push: "$matches",
            },
            offers: {
                $push: "$offers",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            matches: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$matches",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"],
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                    "$doc",
                    {
                        matches: "$matches",
                        offers: "$offers",
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user",
        },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            user: {
                $ifNull: [
                    {
                        $first: "$user",
                    },
                    null,
                ],
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1,
        },
    },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform self-lookup with your criteria set in the sub-pipeline.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      organisationId: "organisationId1",
      matchId: null,
      matchStatus: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$offers"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "let": {
        offersFrom: "$offers.from",
        offersTo: "$offers.to",
        offersLocation: "$offers.locations",
        offersType: "$offers.types"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$from",
                    "$$offersFrom"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    "$to",
                    "$$offersTo"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$in": [
                    "$location",
                    "$$offersLocation"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$in": [
                    "$type",
                    "$$offersType"
                  ]
                },
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "selfLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$selfLookup"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$selfLookup"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gPPn_HFb2nD)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, but I'm not sure this is right. I don't want to retrieve any nested documents, I want to match whole documents that have a compatible from/to/location/type. So in the playground you linked, I just want to match document id2 - this is what is produced by using offers.map(...) in my code above

Comment: @LaurenceSummers It is currently unclear what you are looking for **without an expected output in your question**. Nevertheless, you could be looking for a bit more wrangling to achieve what you want like in the updated version of the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have added an example output but like I said it's just finding the docs that meet the criteria - your updated playground seems to do this but when I try it on the full db the results are wrong and it's very slow

Comment: @LaurenceSummers 1. *the results are wrong* - Please provide some cases in which the code does not match your expected behaviour 2. *it's very slow* - Your expected behaviour involves heavy `$lookup` operation. Either build an index or refactor your schema if that would be a frequent query.

Comment: It's hard to describe it in a comment so have a look a this screen shot: https://ibb.co/bdBgg9d - the matched "from" is before "from" in offers[0] and the matched "location" is missing in the "locations" of offers[0] (offers.length = 1)

Comment: Does this help? A simplified diagram of the criteria https://ibb.co/wpwtCGQ

Comment: @LaurenceSummers no. It's not. Please simply [edit] your question to include plain json documents, not images.